# How to insert the field value in infopath form?

Tags: infopath

I have an **infopath** form ,i am able to retrieve the value from the field using:

```
MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:field1", NamespaceManager).Value;
```

But my question is, how can we insert new value in to that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through all the **properties**,You can find

```
MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode(
    "/my:myFields/my:field1",NamespaceManager).SetValue("Required value");
```

I hope it helps